# Ubuntu unable to mount an USB and breaks it

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount

There are 2 computers using Ubuntu 16.04 and apparently the same config. One works perfectly fine with USB. When I try to insert on the other one I get this error:

```
Unable to access “HDD”

Error mounting /dev/sdb3 at /media/user/HDD: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb3" "/media/user/HDD"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb3': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Then when I try to put it again in the Ubuntu where it previously worked, it shows the same message, effectively rendering it unusable until I repair it with Windows.

What is causing this?

Comment: Did you unmount the stick before you removed it from the computer?

Comment: @mook765 yes I do

Comment: 1. What USB drive is it (brand name model, size)? 2. Are you willing to copy the content to another drive and re-format this USB drive? I can suggest what to do depending on what drive it is.

Comment: Why is Ubuntu asking you to " run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice"?

Comment: @user3169, Because there is no good linux tool to repair NTFS file systems, and Windows needs two reboots to recover fully (make the file system completely fixed and recognized (by Windows itself).